# Select rows that have the same column value based on another column's field values

Tags: mysql

In my table, I have 3 columns with `SubmissionId, FieldName, FieldValue`.
I have a query:

```
SELECT SubmissionId, FieldName, FieldValue 
FROM myTable 
WHERE (FieldValue = "Soccer") 
  OR (FieldValue = "Main Hall") 
  OR (FieldValue = "August 23, 2017")
```

that returns me the following:

### SubmissionId |    FieldName    | FieldValue

```
     1508        | ClassLocation |  Main Hall
     1509        | EventName     |  Soccer
     1512        | EventName     |  Soccer
     1516        | ClassLocation |  Main Hall
     1520        | EventName     |  Soccer
     1520        | EventDate     |  August 23, 2017
     1520        | ClassLocation |  Main Hall
     1523        | EventName     |  Soccer
     1524        | EventName     |  Soccer
     1525        | ClassLocation |  Main Hall
     1538        | EventName     |  Soccer
     1539        | EventName     |  Soccer
     1539        | EventDate     |  August 23, 2017
     1539        | ClassLocation |  Main Hall
     1540        | ClassLocation |  Main Hall
     1550        | ClassLocation |  Main Hall
```

I am now trying to figure out the best way to add on to this query so that I can only get the field value from SubmissionId column that repeats itself three times, in this case it would be submission id's that are 1520 and 1539.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Not related tip: Use `IN` like this `FieldValue IN ('Soccer', 'Main Hall', 'August 23, 2017')`

Comment: What if someone wants to play 'Pool', or the event takes place in the 'Pool'?

Comment: @Strawberry The field values with EventName let's say, is fixed, but the same event 'Soccer', can also be played in another ClassLocation or EventDate, then they will have different SubmissionId's. I am only interested in the results where the SubmissionId is the same for the EventName/EventDate/ClassLocation...

Comment: @MarcinRachwal In which case it seems strange that you search for the values, and not the keys !?!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT SubmissionId, COUNT(SubmissionId) 
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY SubmissionId 
HAVING COUNT(SubmissionId) = 3
```

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SubmissionId
FROM myTable 
WHERE FieldValue in ('Soccer','Main Hall', 'August 23, 2017')
GROUP BY SubmissionID
HAVING count(Distinct fieldName) = 3
```

I use a distinct incase fieldValue could repeat for a given submissionID.

you could also tie in FieldName so you ensure paired mappings

`WHERE (FieldName, FieldValue) in (('EventName','Soccer'),('ClassLocation','Main Hall'),('EventDate','August 23, 2017'))`

Comment: This also works great! I also like the added tie to FieldName for paired mappings, very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Just use your current query as subquery for an aggregation

```
SELECT SubmissionId
FROM ( SELECT SubmissionId, FieldName, FieldValue 
       FROM myTable 
       WHERE FieldValue IN ( "Soccer", "Main Hall", "August 23, 2017")
     ) as T
GROUP BY SubmissionId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: This works great! Looking at it now it is very simple, thank you so much for helping me out with this.